# Incorrect app after obfuscation ProGard

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-proguard

In my application I use **ProGuard**. My proguard-rules file looks like:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.test.**

-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

After building a successful .apk, application it is not working correctly. Missing some TextView, Toast appears, but does not disappear with time, no transitions between Activity work correctly.

As soon as I add `-dontobfuscate`, everything works as it should.

Comment: is your apk working if minify is not enabled?

Comment: Yes, if it is determined `minifyEnabled false` everything works fine

Comment: how did u bind the UI views ?using butterKnife?

Comment: I use a **ButterKnife**. But the tool I use to bind all UI views in app and lost only a few.

Comment: can you bind Views without using butterKnife.I feel it is the one that is creating the trouble.

Comment: I tried to bind UI views using `findViewById`, the same result.